# $model->delete() or $model->save() crashes transaction process: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans3 does not exist

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, transactions

It's been 2 days now I'm trying to fix a problem and am still failing. Thank you to whoever can help on this matter.

**The error**
 I keep getting this message:
`Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans3 does not exist`

There is a complex process during an action, and I need to check several tables. As it goes through several functions, the process generates nested transactions.

It's not the first time I use transactions, and even nested transactions, everything worked so far. Only this function triggers the error.
Even if I remove `the DB::beginTransaction()` and its friends from the function, I stil have the error. Except "trans3" becomes "trans2".

I reduced the function code to the simplest in order to trigger the error:

```
public function doStuff(Stuff $stuff, User $user)
    {
        $thing = Thing::where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('other_id', $stuff->id)
            ->get()
            ->first();
        $thing->delete();

        return false;
}
```

**What I already tried**

- As seen in the simplifed code, removing DB::beginTransaction and such
  doesn't prevent the error.
- I also tried to set a save operation after changing a property from true to false, with `$thing->fill(['property' => false]); $thing->save();`, same error. If the property isn't changed from what is in database, no error (for instance `$thing->fill(['property' => true]); $thing->save();` triggers no error, because no update triggered).
- I tried using `DB::raw('raw SQL')`, no difference.
- I tried `DB::delete('RAW SQL');`, no difference.

**Technical environment**
Laravel 5.5
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.36-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
PHP 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

The only solution I have in mind right now is removing all transactions in all parent code. Even if I ignore the danger it represents, the time required for this is out of scope, so I'd like to make sure there is no other alternative.

Does anyone have any idea, lead, anything ?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your code doesn't have *any* `DB::beginTransaction()` calls before `doStuff()`?

Comment: Yes it does, but I'd like to keep them or else it will require big amount of time.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @Stéphane Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: @JonWhite nope, I implemented a Transaction service. I'll write an answer, but it's not a fix, just a workaround and I don't like it :/

Answer (score 3):

This answer may come way too late but I was having what seems to be the same problem.

It was only when I decided to try removing the transaction that I found there was an underlying error. One of the inserts was causing an integrity constraint violation error which my tests where reporting as `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist`.

Once I resolved the underlying error I restored my transaction and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it works in my local environment, but it fails in CI.
Finally, I found the point.
Local MySQL

```
sql_mode: NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

CI MySQL

```
sql_mode: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I found that when I created the table, I didn't give the default value of the varchar type, and I forgot to write it when I assigned the value.

Therefore, in my case, the main reason is **mysql strict mode**.

May be helpful to you.
(By the way, the framework I am using is not laravel. )

Answer (score 1):

I had this error in a symfony 4 project. It was due to a conflict with [dama/doctrine-test-bundle](https://github.com/dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle)

Error disappeared after removing extension in phpunit config :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, just a workaround, and not really satisfying. But still, it helped me prevent several problems.

I created a TransactionService

```
class TransactionService
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function beginTransaction() {
        if(DB::transactionLevel() === 0) {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $ongoingTransaction
     */
    public function commit($ongoingTransaction) {
        if($ongoingTransaction === true) {
            DB::commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $ongoingTransaction
     */
    public function rollBack($ongoingTransaction) {
        if($ongoingTransaction === true) {
            DB::rollBack();
        }
    }
}
```

And I use DB transactions only through it:

```
$sqlOngoingTransaction = Transaction::beginTransaction();
try {
  // do stuff
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  Transaction::rollBack($sqlOngoingTransaction);
  throw($e);
}

Transaction::commit($sqlOngoingTransaction);
```